# React Child won't update Parent's Hook State

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In my code, I pass the state and the hook to change the state down to a children component. The children component is able to change the value provided, but it isn't able to send this value back to the parent using the hook provided.

I know the code is kinda weird, I am trying to add/remove elements from an array if a checkbox is selected.

Here is the code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, SafeAreaView, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import {generalStyles} from '@gym-app/styles/general'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import persistent from '@gym-app/database/persistent'
import CheckboxRow from '../../components/workout/exercises/filters/CheckboxRow'
import tdb from '@gym-app/translation/object'

export default function ExercisesFilterScreen() {

    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const [equipments, setEquipments] = useState({});
    const [selectedEquipments, setSelectedEquipments] = useState({});

    if(Object.values(equipments).length == 0) {
        persistent.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM equipment', [],
            (t, s) => {
                setEquipments(s.rows._array)
            }, (t, e) => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(selectedEquipments))
      }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView style={[generalStyles.contentContainer, {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffb623'}]}>
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(selectedEquipments)}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>{t('general.filters').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                    <Text style={{ marginBottom: 6, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'left'}}>{t('exercise.availableEquipment').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                    {Object.values(equipments).map((equipment) => {
                        return <CheckboxRow key={equipment.id} selected={selectedEquipments} select={setSelectedEquipments} multi={true} id={equipment.id}>{tdb(equipment, 'name')}</CheckboxRow>
                   })}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Checkbox from './Checkbox'

export default function CheckboxRow(props) {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row}
            onPress={
                () => {
                    var id = props.id;
                    var selected = props.selected;
                    var s = selected;
                    if(props.multi == true) {
                        if(s[id] == undefined) {
                            s[id] = id;
                        } else {
                            delete s[id];
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(s == id) {
                            s = undefined;
                        } else {
                            s = id;
                        }
                    }
                    props.select(s)
                    setChecked(!checked);
                }
            }>
            <Checkbox checked={checked} />
            <Text style={styles.rowText}>{props.children}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    rowText: {
        fontSize: 26,
        color: 'white',
        marginLeft: 6,
        fontWeight: '700'
    }
})
```

The alert in useEffect isn't triggered, so I assume that the state didn't change.

Comment: Does it work if you add `selectedEquipments` to the dependency array for useEffect rather than passing an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument you provide to `useEffect` is an array of dependencies for it to watch to know when to fire.  When you pass an empty array, it only runs on initial mount (and runs the return when unmounted).  If you change that empty array to `[selectedEquipments]` does it work as you intend?